# Combine/Append multiple data worksheets into one summary worksheet and then delete data worksheets

Tags: excel, csv, merge, vba

In my workbook I have a FrontPage sheet with a button. This button imports csv files. Each csv file is imported/copied to its own sheet (let's call them data sheets). This part is complete. In the second part I want to combine all these sheets into one summary sheet and then delete all the data sheets. The second part is almost completed. I only need to figure out how to delete the data sheets once they have been combined into the summary sheet.

Thanks!

This is the code so far:

```
Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Sub CopyDataWithoutHeaders()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long
Dim shLast As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range
Dim StartRow As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"

StartRow = 2

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

        Last = LastRow(DestSh)
        shLast = LastRow(sh)

        If shLast > 0 And shLast >= StartRow Then

            Set CopyRng = sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast))

            If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
               MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the " & _
               "summary worksheet to place the data."
               GoTo ExitTheSub
            End If

            CopyRng.Copy
            With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

        End If

    End If
Next

ExitTheSub:

Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give the sheets convenient names, you can simply loop through all the sheets and delete those called Data[something] for example.

```
 For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    If Left(Worksheets(i).Name, 4) = "Data" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Worksheets(i).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
 Next
```

Looks like you already have 3/4 of the code (the loop, and name check) going on.

Answer (score 0):

After copying what you need to copy, just add:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
sh.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

This deletes the worksheet and removes the requirement for the user to accept / decline the deletion.

Looks like this would go immediately after this block:

```
        CopyRng.Copy
        With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
```